# PHP Function mysql select passing globaly

Tags: php, echo

I'm trying to set up a function that will get me a mysql select from database as I will be using this query a few times. So I thought instead of writing the same select code in each php file I could put it into a function and call it when I want.
So far I'm using this in different files to get results from the database:

```
$stmt_query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE memberID='$id_memberID'");
    $stmt_query->execute();
    $row_query = $stmt_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($row_query as $show_query) {

    $id = $show_query['id'];
    $model = $show_query['model'];
    $year = $show_query['year'];
}
```

And then

```
echo $id; echo $model; echo $year;
```

The question is how can I achieve the same without doing the above multiple times in each different php file?

Answer (score 0):

Write a function like you suggested, just declare your `$db` var as a global since php limits function scope to just the function.

```
function getAll($id_memberID) {
    global $db;
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this function in your code...

```
 function query_fetch(){     
    $stmt_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE memberID='$id_memberID'");

        $row=$stml_query->fetch();
    return $row;
    }
```

Then you can get data by simply using it in while loop.

```
function query_fetch();
    while($row){
     $id = $row['id'];
        $model = $row['model'];
        $year = $row['year'];
    }
```

Or you can use `foreach` as you have used.

And this is also not much...you can repeat if you want..

```
 $stmt_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE memberID='$id_memberID'");        
while($row=$stml_query->fetch()){
 $id = $row['id'];
            $model = $row['model'];
            $year = $row['year'];
}
```

Comment: I'm not using any globals as I'm aware of its evil sides and thanks.

Comment: The above doesn't work. I m using the function fetch_query in function.php and trying to call the $row in another file. Doing the way you described doesn't return anything.

Comment: You probably need to use the `global` keyword, otherwise `$db` is considered a var in local scope. So if your avoiding `global`, go for the last method..It is definitely going to work...

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to notice... :)

Comment: But I have read a lot of articles about using globals and they don't recommend it. I will try it with the global and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a thought...what if I include my functions.php in those other .php files instead? Would that avoid using globals?

Comment: I guess not..once you start dealing inside and outside functions, you have to use `global`. A variable defined inside won't be accessible outside and vice-versa...so you are left with `global` that ways..

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from using globals. globals are worse than singletons which are worse than dependency injection (DI). If you have the ability, go to DI using a dependency injection container right away. This article gives a basic example of how to use DI http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/6014  You would basically set up a bootstrap script for your application, declare the DI container, create your connection, add the connection to the container and then fetch it out of the container and pass it as a parameter to any methods that need it. There are a bunch of easy to setup and use PHP DI containers. PHP-DI and Pimple are two good examples.